# Register Assetbundle in frontend template

Tags: templating, craft3

How can I register an assetbundle in a frontend template?
This is my bundle

```
namespace secondred\formbuilder\assetbundles\Formbuilder;

use Craft;
use craft\web\AssetBundle;
use craft\web\assets\cp\CpAsset;

class FormbuilderAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    // Public Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * Initializes the bundle.
     */
    public function init()
    {
        // define the path that your publishable resources live
        $this->sourcePath = "@secondred/formbuilder/assetbundles/formbuilder/dist";

        // define the dependencies
        $this->depends = [
            CpAsset::class,
        ];

        // define the relative path to CSS/JS files that should be registered with the page
        // when this asset bundle is registered
        $this->js = [
            'js/Formbuilder.js',
        ];

        $this->css = [
            'css/Formbuilder.css',
        ];

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

And I can register it with in my controller without any problems
`$this->view->registerAssetBundle(FormbuilderAsset::class);`

But when I do

```
{% do view.registerAssetBundle("secondred\\formbuilder\\assetbundles\\formbuilder\\FormbuilderAsset") %}
```

nothing happens.. no request, no error, nothing in network tab and no html is added to the page

**Update**

I found the solution. If you are in a frontend ressource you need to call the `{{ endBody() }}` method in order to get the bundles

Comment: A case-sensitivity issue maybe?  Try `{% do view.registerAssetBundle("secondred\\formbuilder\\assetbundles\\Formbuilder\\FormbuilderAsset") %}`

Comment: Thanks Brad, but I found the solution myself.. it was because I didn't call the `{{ endBody() }}` in my frontend template. Maybe it is worth mentioning in the documents? https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/asset-bundles.md

Comment: Yup... added a note to update it.  Would you mind adding that as an official answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
In order to render all the scripts in your registered assetbundles you need to call this function

```
{{ endBody() }}
```

somewhere in your page (preferred at the end of the body)

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to YII2 Advanced Template:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/views/layouts/main.php

Frontend Twig layout template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    {% block head %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    {{ head() }} {# css from AssetBundle #}
    {# {% do view.registerCssFile( "url") %} #} {# Your custom css #}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {{ beginBody() }} {# js from AssetBundle #}
        {% block content %} 
            Hello world! 
        {% endblock %}
    {# {% do view.registerJsFile( "url") %} #}{# Your custom js #}
    {{ endBody() }} {# js from AssetBundle #}
</body>
</html>
```

In your plugin Controller use renderPageTemplate not only renderTemplate. The renderPageTemplate envelops renderTemplate using beginPage() and endPage(), see craft\web\View.php

The combination renderTemplate and {{endBody}} only generates in HTML `<!CDATA ...>` lines.